# ID3-TAG JAVA FileOutputStream

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, id3

Hey guys I wrote a programm that shows me the ID3-Tag of an MP3.file.
Now i would like to change some things in that ID3-TAG for example the year or the title by using the write-method.But i am new to use these kind of classes and don´t really know how to use them.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MP3Auslesen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long groesseMP3 = 0;
        byte bTAG[] = new byte[3];
        byte bTitel[] = new byte[30];
        byte bInterpret[] = new byte[30];
        byte bCDTitel[] = new byte[30];
        byte bJahr[] = new byte[30];
        byte bKommentar[] = new byte[30];

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            System.out.println("MP3-Datei: ");
            String filename = in.readLine();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

            groesseMP3 = fis.available();
            fis.skip(groesseMP3 - 128);

            fis.read(bTAG);
            String strTAG = new String(bTAG);
            fis.read(bTitel);
            String strTitel = new String(bTitel);
            fis.read(bInterpret);
            String strInterpret = new String(bInterpret);
            fis.read(bCDTitel);
            String strCDTitel = new String(bCDTitel);
            fis.read(bJahr);
            String strJahr = new String(bJahr);
            String strKommentar = new String(bKommentar);
            fis.read(bKommentar);
            byte bGenre = (byte) fis.read();

            System.out.println("Dateigröße : " + groesseMP3);
            System.out.println("TAG : " + strTAG);
            System.out.println("Titel :" + strTitel);
            System.out.println("Interpret :" + strInterpret);
            System.out.println("CD-Titel : " + strCDTitel);
            System.out.println("Jahr :" + strJahr);
            System.out.println("Kommentar : " + strKommentar);
            System.out.println("Genre : " + bGenre);
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println("Fehler" + err);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to "invent a wheel" and would like to suggest use special library for that:

[mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic)
[Beaglebuddy](http://www.beaglebuddy.com/)
[Jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples.jsp)

PS: Please read how you can close resource correct (since JDK 1.7) -
[The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)